# React.js and referring autoHide as a property

Tags: reactjs, components, materialize

I have a Materialize-css component that I'm trying to convert to React. It's the `DeterminatePreloader`. I want to have the `autoHide` property on hand to set the variable `show` to `false` if `autoHide` is `true`. The `autoHide`, since it is a property, should be available for setting should a function call it. I would very much appreciate input. Examples I find are either too general or too specific.

Here is my code so far:

```
var React = require('react');

/**
 * Linear Determinate Preloader
 *
 * Materialize CSS converted to React Component
 *
 * @author samtapucar
 */

var DeterminatePreloader = <determinatePreloader autoHide={false}/>;

var DeterminatePreloader = React.createClass({

  /**
   * Initializes determinate preloader state
   * @returns {{percent: number, show: boolean}}
   */
  getInitialState: function ()
  {
    return{
      percent: 0,
      show: true
    };
  },

  /**
   * Sets determinate preloader state using received value
   * @param value
   */
  setValue: function (value)
  {
    var state = this.state;
    state.percent = value;

    if ( state.percent >= 100 ){
      this.props.autoHide = true;
    }

    if ( this.props.autoHide ) {
      state.show = false;
      this.setState(state);
    }
    else{
      this.setState(state);
    }
  },

  /**
   * Renders the determinate preloader.
   * @returns {XML}
   */
  render: function ()
  {
    var percent = this.state.percent;

    var cx = '';

    var style = {
      'width': percent + '%'
    };

    if (!this.state.show)
      cx = ' hide'


    return (
        <div className={"progress" + cx}>
          <div className={'determinate'} style={style}></div>
        </div>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = DeterminatePreloader;
```

Answer (score 0):

There some issues with your code.

1. You're defining `DeterminatePreloader` twice. The first statement is
   unnecessary, because you didn't define the component yet. If you
   want to set the default of `autoHide` use the `getDefaultProps`
   method.
2. `state` should contain as little as possible. The method `render`
   should calculate the `show` variable, since it depends from
   `percent` and `autoHide`. I would also pass `percent` as props since
   you do not have any logic in this component.
3. `state` **should never be overwritten directly**. You should always
   create a new object change it with `setState`.

---

```
var React = require('react');

/**
 * Linear Determinate Preloader
 *
 * Materialize CSS converted to React Component
 *
 * @author samtapucar
 */

var DeterminatePreloader = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      autoHide: false,
      percent: 0
    };
  }
  /**
   * Renders the determinate preloader.
   * @returns {ReactComponent}
   */
  render: function () {   
    var style = {
      'width': this.props.percent + '%'
    };

    var cx = '';

    if (this.props.percent >= 100 && this.props.autoHide)
      cx = ' hide';

    return (
        <div className={"progress" + cx}>
          <div className="determinate" style={style}></div>
        </div>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = DeterminatePreloader;
```

I would also recommend reading [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html). It helps you get the right felling for programming in react.